# How can we create UIlabels with the help of for loop using autolayouts?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my project I am using auto-layouts and I am adding one or more labels on my view-controller and for this I would like to use a "for" loop by means of code reducing purpose but using "constraintWithVisualFormate".

I do not understand!

How can I use a for loop?

### my code:

```
emailTextField = [[UILabel alloc] init];
emailTextField.text = @"MD (Medician)";
emailTextField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
emailTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self.view addSubview: emailTextField];

nameTextField = [[UILabel alloc] init];
nameTextField.text = @"Experience:12 Years";
nameTextField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
nameTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self.view addSubview: nameTextField];

password = [[UILabel alloc] init];
password.text = @"Experience:12 Years";
password.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
password.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self.view addSubview: password];


//Applying auto-layouts for labels

NSDictionary * views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(emailTextField,nameTextField,password);

NSArray *textFields = @[emailTextField, nameTextField, password];

for (UITextField *textField in textFields) {

   [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[textField]-10-|"
                                                                     options:0
                                                                     metrics:nil
                                                                       views:viewsDic]];
}
```

I am struggling near above for loop because I am not understand how can we insert `nameTextField`,`emailTextField`...etc labels inside for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Screenshot

[image]

Code

```
 emailTextField = [self createLabelWithText: @"MD (Medician)"];
[self.view addSubview: emailTextField];

nameTextField = [self createLabelWithText: @"Experience:12 Years"];
[self.view addSubview: nameTextField];

passwword = [self createLabelWithText: @"Experience:12 Years"];
[self.view addSubview: passwword];

NSDictionary * viewsDic = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(emailTextField,nameTextField,passwword);

NSArray * keys = @[@"emailTextField",@"nameTextField",@"passwword"];

for (NSString * key in keys) {
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:|-10-[%@]-10-|",key]
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:viewsDic]];
}
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-20-[emailTextField]-[nameTextField]-[passwword]"
                                                                  options:0
                                                                  metrics:nil
                                                                    views:viewsDic]];
```

This is the function

```
-(UILabel *)createLabelWithText:(NSString *)text{
    UILabel * label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    label.text = text;
    label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    return label;
}
```